# jQuery jPlayer issue in IE

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I have an issue, following code is not working in Internet Explorer:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            // alert("test");
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3:"media/music.mp3",
            }).jPlayer("play");
        },
        swfPath: "js/",
        solution: "flash, html",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window",
        loop: "true"
        });

        });

    </script>

    ...

    <div id="jquery_jplayer">
    </div>
    <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a>
    </div>

    ...
```

Unfortunately it doesn't even alert me something.. :(

Has anybody any hints?

Comment: the alert() is commented out ... typo maybe ? did you include the jPlayer js file ?

Comment: make sure that you called jquery and jPlayer.js

Comment: Hm yes I commented out for here. And I called both jPlayer.js and jquery. It works fine in FF.. :(

Comment: What version of jPlayer ? what version of Internet Explorer?

Comment: Man ok, solved. Sorry the comma behind the .mp3 file made the trick... donk

Comment: Mike, you should mark this question as solved by choosing a solution rather than by stating the solution in a comment, give credit where credit is due. @ManseUK deserves the points, he responded with the solution fastest.

Answer (score 3):

There maybe couple issues going on here...
1. Make sure your path to  swfPath: "js/" file is correct. It should point to a swf file for IE to work. I used fiddler to see if it was getting a 404 error when downloading the swf file.

1. There is an extra comma after the mp3 assignment.
2. This is a suggestion but you can turn errorAlerts to true.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {

   $("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer({
   ready: function () {
       // alert("test");
       $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
           mp3:"media/music.mp3"
       }).jPlayer("play");
   },
   swfPath: "/jquery-jplayer/something.swf", ---not sure what this path will be
   solution: "flash, html",
   supplied: "mp3",
   wmode: "window",
   loop: "true",
   errorAlerts:"true"
   });

   });
   ```

Answer (score 2):

This is IE picking up on your comma after `mp3"` - remove that and it will work fine

```
       $("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer({
          ready: function () {
            // alert("test");
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3:"media/music.mp3"    // <--- Remove the comma
            }).jPlayer("play");
        },
```